# flags in flex regexpvalidator

Tags: regex, apache-flex, validation

can anyone please explain me what is the use of flag variable in the flex RegExpValidator.
what I am  to do is to create a validator that can provide variety of error messages as in EmailValidator

Answer (score 0):

These have nothing to do with output messages. It's to specify the behavior of the regexp matcher. Here is the list of available flags: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea7.html

If you want to build a more complex validator you'll have to extend `Validator` from scratch.